# How do you disable dead code warnings at the crate level in Rust?

Tags: rust, compiler-warnings

While tinkering in Rust, I repeatedly encountered a lot of dead code warnings that made it difficult to focus. I tried using the outer attribute `#[allow(dead_code)]`, but it only silences one warning at a time.

```rust
struct SemanticDirection;

fn main() {}
```

```plaintext
warning: struct `SemanticDirection` is never constructed
 --> src\main.rs:1:8
  |
1 | struct SemanticDirection;
  |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(dead_code)]` on by default
```

How do I disable these warnings at the crate level?

Answer (score 816, accepted):

You can either:

- Add an [`allow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes/diagnostics.html#lint-check-attributes) attribute on a struct, module, function, etc.:

  ```
  #[allow(dead_code)]
  struct SemanticDirection;
  ```
- Add an `allow` as a [crate-level attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27454761/155423); notice the `!`:

  ```
  #![allow(dead_code)]
  ```
- Pass it to `rustc`:

  ```bash
  rustc -A dead_code main.rs
  ```
- Pass it using `cargo` via the `RUSTFLAGS` environment variable:

  ```bash
  RUSTFLAGS="$RUSTFLAGS -A dead_code" cargo build
  ```

Comment: Note that the last one will trigger recompilation of everything.

Comment: The last one works best IMO. Also adding `-A unused_variables` can be helpful to prevent dealing with with placing `_` in front of everything.

Comment: `#![allow(dead_code)]` also have to go before any code otherwise rust gives some cryptic error.

Comment: would allow(dead_code) bloat the final binary size? or would that not happen?

Comment: @user1709076 i don't think that it could bloat the binary size since its just a warning and is displayed only at compile time

Comment: on windows in powershell setting the environment variable and running it works with this command: `$Env:RUSTFLAGS="-A dead_code -A unused_variables"; cargo run`

Answer (score 114):

Another way to disable this warning is to prefix the identifier by `_`:

```
struct _UnusedStruct {
    _unused_field: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let _unused_variable = 10;
}
```

This can be useful, for instance, with an SDL window:

```
let _window = video_subsystem.window("Rust SDL2 demo", 800, 600);
```

Prefixing with an underscore is different from using a lone underscore as the name. Doing the following will immediately destroy the window, which is unlikely to be the intended behavior.

```
let _ = video_subsystem.window("Rust SDL2 demo", 800, 600);
```

Comment: That "assigning to underscore will destroy it" behavior seems odd (though I don't doubt you're correct). Do you have a reference for it?

Comment: @MichaelAnderson See "RAII. You might want to have a variable exist for its destructor side effect, but not use it otherwise. It is not possible to use simply _ for this use-case, as _ is not a variable binding and the value would be dropped at the end of the statement." from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48361729/109618

Comment: using `let _ =` the value would be dropped at the end of the statement, not the end of the block

Comment: If you want to read more about why, the reason is that the `X` in `let X = Y` is an irrefutable pattern (i.e. it's like a `match` arm that can be proved to never be wrong at compile time) and, like with refutable patterns, `_` is a wildcard that doesn't bind anything to a variable. That's why and how you can do `let (x, y) = foo();` and other sorts of unpacking like that. It's just another kind of irrefutable pattern.

Answer (score 77):

**Put these two lines at the top of the file:**

```
#![allow(dead_code)]
#![allow(unused_variables)]
```

Comment: what's the difference those two? #[allow(dead_code)] not works but #![allow(dead_code)] works.

Comment: @jwkoo the ! makes it apply to the entire crate

Comment: Replace with `#![allow(dead_code, unused)]` ;-)

Comment: @jaques-sam `dead_code` and `unused_variables` are subsets of `unused` (with many more lints) which likely is too board to silence the linter for something specific. The different between the lints is detailed in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64556868/175584

Comment: would allow bloat of the final binary size? or would that not happen?

Comment: @user1709076 `allow` annotations only influence the compiler diagnostics (warnings/errors). They don't change anything for the final binary and usually the compiler is smart enough to remove unused code/variables. Unused code of course still impacts compile time and *might* increase binary size, regardless of the use of `allow`.

Answer (score 37):

Making the code **public** also stops the warnings; you'll need to make the enclosing `mod`'s public too.

This makes sense when you're writing a library: your code is "unused" internally because it's intended to be used by client code.

Comment: I think this does not work if the crate contains both a main.rs and a lib.rs, and the main.rs does not use the function under question.

Answer (score 12):

also as an addition: rust provides five levels of lints (allow, warn, force-warn, deny, forbid).

https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/lints/levels.html#lint-levels

Answer (score 9):

- Directly way to just put the following in the **head** of the file

  `#![allow(dead_code, unused_variables)]`

  - The `dead_code` lint detects unused, unexported items.
  - The `unused_variables` lint detects variables which are not used in any way.
- More simple way is to put the following in the **head** of the file

  `#![allow(unused)]`

Ref: [rust lint list](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/lints/listing/warn-by-default.html)

Answer (score 6):

You can add the #[allow(dead_code)] attribute to the struct definition like so:

```
#[allow(dead_code)]
struct SemanticDirection;
```

Or you can disable the warning for the entire file by adding the attribute at the top of the file, like so:

```
#![allow(dead_code)]

struct SemanticDirection;
```

But these attributes only work if you have the dead_code lint enabled. By default, the dead_code lint is enabled in Rust, but you can disable it by adding the following to the top of your code:

```
#![deny(dead_code)]
```

This will disable the dead_code lint for the entire file.

It's generally a good idea to keep the dead_code lint enabled, as it can help you catch mistakes in your code and ensure that you are not introducing unnecessary code into your project. However, it can be annoying when you are just experimenting and trying out different things, so it's understandable if you want to disable it in those cases.

Answer (score 5):

For unused functions, you should make the function public, but watch out. If the struct isn't public, then you'll still get the error as in here:

```
//this should be public also
struct A{
   A{}
}

impl A {
    pub fn new() -> A {

    }
}
```

Or if you don't want it to be public, you should put `#[allow(unused)]`

Answer (score 3):

You can always disable unused variables/functions by adding an (_) to the variable name, like so:

```
let _variable = vec![0; 10];
```

Comment: antoyo's answer already covers this approach.

Answer (score 3):

At the top of `*.rs` file:

```rust
#![allow(unused)]  // FIXME
```

Answer (score 2):

Since [Rust 1.74.0](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2023/11/16/Rust-1.74.0.html#lint-configuration-through-cargo) you can also configure lints at the crate level with new section `[lints]` in the *Cargo Manifest*. Detailed explanation can be found in the [Cargo Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-lints-section), but here is the simple example.

Following attributes in the root of the crate:

```rust
#![allow(unused)]
#![forbid(unsafe_code)]
#![deny(clippy::enum_glob_use)]
```

can be expressed in `Cargo.toml` as:

```ini
[lints.rust]
unused = "allow"
unsafe_code = "forbid"

[lints.clippy]
enum_glob_use = "deny"
```

Answer (score 1):

add this in 1st line of code

```
#![allow(unused_variables)]
```

all warnings solutions:

https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/lints/listing/warn-by-default.html

Comment: It seems this helps only for this specific warning (unused variables). Using `#![allow(unused)]` seems tot fix all unused warnings (e.g. unused macros, imports, dead code, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Others have already answered how to do this in code using `#[allow(dead_code)]`, but if you are a Windows User like myself who wants to do this in the command line, the exact format is slightly different. Type in the below lines before you run any `cargo` commands to set environment variables:

To disable Rust's checking for **dead code**:

```
set RUSTFLAGS=-A dead_code
```

To disable Rust's checking for **unused variables**:

```
set RUSTFLAGS=-A unused_variables
```

To disable Rust's checking for **dead code and unused variables**:

```
set RUSTFLAGS= -A dead_code -A unused_variables
```

To **revert** Rust to its previous behavior:

```
set RUSTFLAGS=
```

After that, Cargo will behave the way you tell it to until you close command line.

If you want prefer to run both `set RUSTFLAGS` and `cargo` commands on a **single line** using the **'&' separator**, here are all the above examples with `cargo build` added:

```
set RUSTFLAGS=-A dead_code & cargo build
set RUSTFLAGS=-A unused_variables & cargo build
set RUSTFLAGS=-A dead_code -A unused_variables & cargo build
set RUSTFLAGS=& cargo build
```

Answer (score -10):

using features

```
#[cfg(feature = "dead_code")]
```

note: `"dead_code"` can be replaced by any word.

Comment: I have never seen cfg/feature used like this. Can you explain how this works, or is it documented somewhere?