# How to disable the unused macros warning?

Tags: macros, rust

This code:

```
#[allow(dead_code)]
macro_rules! test {
    ($x:expr) => {{}}
}

fn main() {

    println!("Results:")

}
```

produces the following warning about unused macro definition:

```
warning: unused macro definition
  --> /home/xxx/.emacs.d/rust-playground/at-2017-08-02-031315/snippet.rs:10:1
   |
10 | / macro_rules! test {
11 | |     ($x:expr) => {{}}
12 | | }
   | |_^
   |
   = note: #[warn(unused_macros)] on by default
```

Is it possible to suppress it? As you can see `#[allow(dead_code)` doesn't help in case of macros.

Comment: I don't know rust, but it looks like  `#[allow(unused_macros)]` might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The compiler warning states:

```
= note: #[warn(unused_macros)] on by default
```

Which is very similar to the warning caused by unused functions:

```
= note: #[warn(dead_code)] on by default
```

You can disable these warnings in the same way, but you need to use the matching macro attribute:

```
#[allow(unused_macros)]
macro_rules! test {
    ($x:expr) => {{}}
}
```

Comment: Notably, this should only disable the warning for this specific macro, right? [For future newbies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25877389/2550406)