# Why does _ destroy at the end of statement?

Tags: syntax, rust, pattern-matching

I've seen a few other questions and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25877389/221955) stating that `let _ = foo()` destroys the result at the end of the statement rather than at scope exit, which is what `let _a = foo()` does.

I am unable to find any official description of this, nor any rationale for this syntax.

I'm interested in a few inter-twined things:

- Is there even a mention of it in the official documentation?
- What is the history behind this choice? Is it simply natural fall-out from Rust's binding / destructuring rules? Is it something inherited from another language? Or does it have some other origin?
- Is there some use-case this syntax addresses that could not have been achieved using explicit scoping?

Answer (score 8):

> Is it simply natural fall-out from Rust's binding / destructuring rules?

Yes. You use `_` to indicate that you don't care about a value in a pattern and that it should not be bound in the first place. If a value is never bound to a variable, there's nothing to hold on to the value, so it must be dropped.

[All the Places Patterns Can Be Used](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch18-01-all-the-places-for-patterns.html):

- `match` Arms
- Conditional `if let` Expressions
- `while let` Conditional Loops
- `for` Loops
- `let` Statements
- Function Parameters

> Is there even a mention of it in the official documentation?

[Ignoring an Entire Value with `_`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#ignoring-an-entire-value-with-_)

Of note is that `_` isn't [a valid identifier](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/identifiers.html), thus you can't use it as a name:

```
fn main() {
    let _ = 42;
    println!("{}", _);
}
```

```
error: expected expression, found reserved identifier `_`
 --> src/main.rs:3:20
  |
3 |     println!("{}", _);
  |                    ^ expected expression
```

> achieved using explicit scoping

I suppose you could have gone this route and made expressions doing this just "hang around" until the scope was over, but I don't see any value to it:

```
let _ = vec![5];    
vec![5]; // Equivalent
// Gotta wait for the scope to end to clean these up, or call `drop` explicitly
```

Comment: I'm still not sure why it is natural fall-out from the binding / destructuring rules. Are there other  `let pattern = fn()` type constructs, other than the pure `_`? (I'm not yet familiar with all rusts idioms - so this is an honest question.)

Comment: @MichaelAnderson yes, all `let` statements take patterns as the LHS. See [the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/statements.html#let-statements). This allows tuple destructuring to work for example: `let (a, b) = (1, 2);`

Answer (score 5):

The only reason that you'd use `let _ = foo()` is when the function requires that you use its result, and you know that you don't need it. Otherwise, this:

```
let _ = foo();
```

is exactly the same as this:

```
foo();
```

For example, suppose `foo` has a signature like this:

```
fn foo() -> Result<String, ()>;
```

You will get a warning if you don't use the result, because [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/result.rs.html#254) has the [`#[must_use]` attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes.html#must_use-attribute). Destructuring and ignoring the result immediately is a concise way of avoiding this warning in cases where you know it's ok, without introducing a new variable that lasts for the full scope.

If you didn't pattern match against the result then the value would be dropped as soon as the `foo` function returns. It seems reasonable that Rust would behave the same regardless of whether you explicitly said you don't want it or just didn't use it.