# How can I import a single function from a module in Rust?

Tags: import, module, rust, unused-variables

I'm fairly new to Rust and coming from Python there are some things that are done very differently. In Python, one can import a single function from a .py file by typing `from foo import bar`, but I still haven't found any equivalent in Rust.

I have the following files:

```
.
├── main.rs
└── module.rs
```

With the following contents:

#### main.rs

```
mod module;

fn main() {
    module::hello();
}
```

#### module.rs

```
pub fn hello() {
    println!("Hello");
}

pub fn bye() {
    println!("Bye");
}
```

How do I create my module or type my imports so that I don't get the following warning:

```
warning: function is never used: `bye`
  --> module.rs:5:1
   |
 5 |     pub fn bye() {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: #[warn(dead_code)] on by default
```

Comment: It seems like you should clarify your question. Is the issue `hello` or `bye`? Why are both included, if the question is about importing `bye`? The warning is expected because `bye` is never used right now.

Comment: Your second unrelated question is probably answered by [How to disable unused code warnings in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25877285/155423) although the true answer for "how do I get rid of unused code" is to *delete that code*.

Comment: In this particular case, if you have some reason to keep the unused function, you can get rid of the warning by making the module public: `pub mod module`.  Rust does not warn about public unused code by default, since the assumption is that these functions could be used by other projects depending on your code as a library.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's nothing materially different from importing a module vs a type vs a function vs a trait:

```
use path::to::function;
```

For example:

```
mod foo {
    pub fn bar() {}
}

use foo::bar;

fn main() {
    bar();
}
```