# How to get rid of the never used warning without turning off the warning?

Tags: rust

I have a crate with **main.rs** and **types.rs**. **types.rs** is used as `mod types;` in **main.rs**.

I'm designing **types.rs** as a library which contains functions/fields that may not be used by **main.rs**, but the compiler gives me uncountable warnings about something "is never used".

What is the correct solution here?

Comment: if it supposed to be a lib, then why aren't you creating a `lib.rs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution could be to create a `lib.rs` at the same level as your `main.rs` which will become your crate which you would be able to `use` things from.  The `mod types;` should go into the `lib.rs` and then you can pick the things you'd like to be available for the outside world via `pub use`.

Inside a module, if something is not marked as `pub` then it has to be used -- hence the warning.

You could [temporarily disable warnings while you are developing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25877389/2188562).

Comment: Thanks. Does it have to be named "lib.rs"? By the second paragraph, I did have all fn/struct prefixed with pub, which I thought to be the way to work. But I got the warning.

Comment: Well, yes, there are a few special naming conventions in rust, such as `main.rs` for executable programs, `lib.rs` for crates, and `mod.rs` to turn directories into modules.  Are you still using stuff from your `types.rs` directly or from your crate?

Comment: I have to do: mod types; pub use types::*; in lib.rs to make it work.... Strange.

Comment: not strange at all, that's exactly how it supposed to work.  you are creating a crate.  a crate is a "super module" or "module of modules".  your types module is just part of that crate.  your executable will be using your crate.  It all make perfect sense, don't you think?

Comment: (on a side note: you probably don't want to do `pub use types::*;` global "exports" are not necessarily the things you want to have, you could/should be more specific there)

Comment: I see. Just not quite used to controlling what is exposed to crate and what is exposed to outside by the same "pub".