# What is the difference between the dead_code and unused lints?

Tags: rust, compiler-warnings

What is the difference between

```rust
#[allow(dead_code)]
// ...some code
```

and

```rust
#[allow(unused)]
// ...some code
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`dead_code`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/lints/listing/warn-by-default.html#dead-code) is one specific lint that [is defined as](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.47.0/src/librustc_session/lint/builtin.rs#L107-L111):

```rust
declare_lint! {
    pub DEAD_CODE,
    Warn,
    "detect unused, unexported items"
}
```

`unused` is a [*lint group*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/lints/groups.html) that is composed of `dead_code` and many other lints. It [is defined as](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.47.0/src/librustc_lint/lib.rs#L264-L287):

```rust
add_lint_group!(
    "unused",
    UNUSED_IMPORTS,
    UNUSED_VARIABLES,
    UNUSED_ASSIGNMENTS,
    DEAD_CODE,
    UNUSED_MUT,
    UNREACHABLE_CODE,
    UNREACHABLE_PATTERNS,
    OVERLAPPING_PATTERNS,
    UNUSED_MUST_USE,
    UNUSED_UNSAFE,
    PATH_STATEMENTS,
    UNUSED_ATTRIBUTES,
    UNUSED_MACROS,
    UNUSED_ALLOCATION,
    UNUSED_DOC_COMMENTS,
    UNUSED_EXTERN_CRATES,
    UNUSED_FEATURES,
    UNUSED_LABELS,
    UNUSED_PARENS,
    UNUSED_BRACES,
    REDUNDANT_SEMICOLONS
);
```

Comment: For those interested in terminology, ["items"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items.html) are almost anything that can be declared at the module level: structs, traits, enums, functions, statics, etc.